# Why can't I use triggers in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am doing a project for my school library. There is a Member table which has registered date, expiry date and renew date attributes. Now when a new member is registering I want to have a trigger which will insert the current date for the registered date, renew date and since the membership will be valid for 2 years, the expiry date should be set to two years from the current date. Now I have written triggers for this but when I go to insert a new member I get the following error.

- Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'member' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

This is my trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger regDate
before insert on member
for each row begin
    set @currentDate = CURDATE();
    set @expDate = ADDDATE(@currentDate, INTERVAL 2 year);
    insert into member(regDate, expDate, renewDate) values (@currentDate, @expDate, @currentDate);
end$$
```

I have searched for a solution and only comes to a dead end where someone says it's a bug in MySQL!

Comment: That would lead to an endless loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning the values via [`NEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html):

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger regDate
before insert on member
for each row begin
    set @currentDate = CURDATE();
    set @expDate = ADDDATE(@currentDate, INTERVAL 2 year);
    set new.regDate = @currentDate;
    set new.expDate = @expDate;
    set new.renewDate= @currentDate;
end$$
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [trigger FAQ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-9):

> A trigger can access both old and new data in its own table. A trigger can also affect other tables, but **it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.** (Before MySQL 5.0.10, a trigger cannot modify other tables.)

You don't `insert` *explicitly* within the trigger in this case, simply change the `new.<columnName>` value and the trigger will use that to automagically modify the row.

In other words, replace:

```
insert into member(regDate, expDate, renewDate) values (
    @currentDate, @expDate, @currentDate);
```

with:

```
set new.regDate = @currentDate;
set new.expDate = @expDate;
set new.renewDate = @currentDate;
```

There are some decent examples on the [trigger syntax page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) and remember that the old row data values are accessible from `old.<columnName>`.